# moment.js returns different timezones

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, utc, timezone-offset

I'm using this code to create 2 dates that represent a filter date range (in this case the last 3 months):

```
$ctrl.startDate = moment().utc().startOf('month').add(-2, 'months').toDate();
$ctrl.endDate = moment().utc().endOf('month').add(0, 'months').toDate();
```

However the first returned date is timezone CET (GMT+1) (which is my zone) and the second is CEST (GMT+2). I have no idea why! I have tried using utc() to get "neutral" dates without success.

Returned dates:

01.01.2017 01:00:00 CET

01.04.2017 01:59:59 CEST

I want either GMT or CET but the **same** zone! Where does moment take these 2 zones from?

I've come so far that I think it is a bug.

I use version 2.17.1

Any ideas?

JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/8807/

Comment: Not a bug; April is after the switch over from standard to daylight saving time. That's what the extra "S" means.

Comment: You may wish to read the [`dst` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) and the [`timezone` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for further information.

Comment: Also, you can read about the March 26, 2017 DST switch for Europe [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/europe-starts-dst-2017.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can consider it a bug, in your fiddle you are showing in the result of [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) that as docs says:

> get the native Date object that Moment.js wraps

If you look at [momentjs the code](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.17.1/moment.js#L3296) you will see that `toDate()` implementation:

```
function toDate () {
    return new Date(this.valueOf());
}
```

simply uses `new Date()` that returns a JavaScript date object in **local** time, see [MDN Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters):

> **Note:** Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specifed arguments represent local time. If UTC is desired, use new Date([Date.UTC(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)) with the same arguments.

If you use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) in your code you will always see `+00:00` offset.

```js
var divUtc = $('#divUTC');
var divLocal = $('#divLocal');  

var startDate = moment.utc().startOf('month').add(-2, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
var endDate = moment.utc().endOf('month').add(0, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
//put UTC time into divUTC  
divUtc.text(startDate);      
divLocal.text(endDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.7/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>

UTC<br/>
<div id="divUTC"></div><br/>
Your Local Time with respect to above UTC time<br/>
<div id="divLocal">
</div>
```